# Select control with multiple="false' allows multiple selections

Tags: html, google-chrome

So far I've tested in Chrome and Firefox.

I have a control set up like this:

```
<select id="MvcDynamicField_7c5d48c48a9d44d2a89c7ec87ac91b9d" multiple="False" name="MvcDynamicField_7c5d48c48a9d44d2a89c7ec87ac91b9d" size="4">
  <option value="2204768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Nerd</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2304768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Geek</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2404768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Jock</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2504768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Crafter</option>
  <option value="2604768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Wallflower</option>
  <option value="bf60c742-dc41-e511-b962-00215e466552">Bossy</option>
</select>
```

I can select more than one item on the page tho. Why?

Comment: if multiple attribute exist in SELECT than it will allow multiple selection, true or false does not make any change to functionality

Comment: if you want to disable multi selection functionality remove multiple attribute

Comment: Thanks. That was the solution. If you post as an answer, I'll up-vote you. It's been a while since I dealt with raw HTML, and I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Multple set to false **does** work. However, multiple is not what makes you see an open/expanded select box. SIZE is what does that. So if you have the size attribute
with a value higher than 1 then it *looks like* multiple = false is not working. 
SO you must also set size to 1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to remove multiselect attribute (multiple="false" )

```
<select id="MvcDynamicField_7c5d48c48a9d44d2a89c7ec87ac91b9d" name="MvcDynamicField_7c5d48c48a9d44d2a89c7ec87ac91b9d" size="4">
  <option value="2204768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Nerd</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2304768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Geek</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2404768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Jock</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2504768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Crafter</option>
  <option value="2604768b-0741-e511-b962-00215e466552">Wallflower</option>
  <option value="bf60c742-dc41-e511-b962-00215e466552">Bossy</option>
</select>
```